# Centralisers in nilpotent Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, nilpotent-groups

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero, let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra over $K$, and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a self-centralising abelian ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$, and we assume that $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ is also abelian.

Given an element $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ and a subset $Y$ of $\mathfrak{h}$, we denote:

$C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x):=\{u\in\mathfrak{h}:[x,u]=0\}$,

$C_{\mathfrak{g}}(Y):=\{v\in\mathfrak{g}:[y,v]=0$ for all $y\in Y\}$.

My question is, can we find an element $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ such that $x\notin\mathfrak{h}$, and if $\mathcal{Z}$ is the centre of $\mathfrak{g}$ then:

\begin{equation}
\dim_{K}\mathfrak{g}\geq \dim_K C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x)+\dim_K{C_{\mathfrak{g}}(C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x))}-\dim_K\mathcal{Z}.
\end{equation}

Any ideas or counterexamples would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is Abelian, then there is no such element, since $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{g}$ in this case. So the answer is no for Abelian Lie algebras.

Now let $g'\neq 0$. From the conditions we get $\mathcal{Z},\mathfrak{g}'\subseteq \mathfrak{h}$, and $C_\mathfrak{h}(x)$ is an Abelian ideal for all $x\in \mathfrak{g}$. Our statement then reads $\dim \mathfrak{g}/C_\mathfrak{h}(x) \geq \dim C_\mathfrak{g}(C_\mathfrak{h}(x))/\mathcal{Z}$ which is certainly true, as $Z\subseteq C_\mathfrak{h}(x)$. Since this is true for any element, the only remaining question is, whether there is such an ideal $\mathfrak{h}\subsetneq \mathfrak{g}$ at all.

Comment: You say it is true that $\dim\mathfrak{g}/C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x)\geq\dim C_{\mathfrak{g}}(C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x))/\mathcal{Z}$ because $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x)$. I can see why this works if $\mathcal{Z}=C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x)$, but otherwise, I'm not sure why it should be true, are you saying that there is any injective map from $C_{\mathfrak{g}}(C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x))/\mathcal{Z}$ to $\mathfrak{g}/C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x)$?

Comment: The dimension of a factor space $A/B$ is $\dim A-\dim B$. Now if $A'\supseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B$ then $\dim A'-\dim B' \geq \dim A -\dim B$, i.e. $\dim A'/B' \geq \dim A/B$.

Comment: But you seem to be taking $B'$ to be $C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x)$ and $B$ to be $\mathcal{Z}$, and in this case $B'\not\subseteq B$.

Comment: We have $\mathcal{Z} \subseteq C_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{h})=\mathfrak{h}$ and it certainly centralizes $x$, so $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq C_\mathfrak{h}(x)$.
You're right, I confused the minus sign, sorry.

Comment: That's OK, thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Your conditions are so strong, there must be a solution one way or the other. We have that $\mathcal{I}:=C_\mathfrak{h}(x)$ is an Abelian ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$ and we have $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq \mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$. That doesn't leave much room.

Answer (score 0):

Assume such an example exists. Then $[x,\mathfrak{h}]=0$ implies $x\in C_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{h})=\mathfrak{h}$ which is a contradiction. There are no examples with the required properties. $x$ has to be in $\mathfrak{h}$ and $C_\mathfrak{h}(x)=\mathfrak{h}=C_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{h})=C_\mathfrak{g}(C_\mathfrak{h}(x))$

Comment: But I'm not assuming that $[x,\mathfrak{h}]=0$.

Comment: I have tried to create a counterexample under the assumption
$$
\mathcal{Z}\subsetneq C_{\mathfrak{h}}(x) \subsetneq \mathfrak{h}  \subsetneq C_{\mathfrak{g}}(C_\mathfrak{h}(x)) \subsetneq \mathfrak{g}
$$
by consecutively adding a basis vector, and always failed with the self-centralising condition.

Comment: I think I have a counterexample. Let 
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\mathcal{Z}+ kA+kB+kH+kX+kY
$$
and $[H,X]=A,[H,Y]=B,[X,Y]=Z\in \mathcal{Z}-\{0\}$ the only non zero multiplications. Set $\mathfrak{h}=\mathcal{Z}+kA+kB+kH$, and $x=X$.

If I try something new and made no mistake this time, then I get $C_\mathfrak{h}(X)=\mathcal{Z}+kA+kB$ and $C_\mathfrak{g}(C_\mathfrak{h}(X))=\mathfrak{g}$ and your formula yields $0\geq 2.$

Comment: We need to add $[A,Y]=Z_1,[B,Y]=Z_2$ to make the center smaller, but I'm not sure whether these additions destroy some of the other conditions.

Comment: Yes, in your first example, $A$ and $B$ were central, and thus $\mathcal{Z}$ is not the full centre. The problem is, you would need to define relations for $[A,X]$ and $[B,X]$ as well as $[A,Y]$ and $[B,Y]$ in order for the bracket to satisfy the Jacobi identity, and this would make $C_{\mathfrak{h}}(X)$ smaller.